# Lightweight pure C HTTP GET implementation

Tags: c, http

I am looking for a pure C, lightweight HTTP GET implementation. Preferably not a precompiled library, but more like how SQLite is distributed as one big C file that I can compile and link in my own code.

The reason I need this, is that I have a embedded application that needs to connect to a server to fetch some files. The embedded device is connected to the internet by (sometimes) flaky mobile connection.

I have implemented it now using shell scripts that use `wget` in `busybox` to do the fetching, but it seems they sometimes don't work. Download failures and other script errors are not easy to catch (the script is started from a piece of C firmware).

Comment: Perhaps something like [`libcurl`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/)? Haven't used it myself so I can't tell you how lightweight it is, but that might be a good place to start.

Comment: `libcurl` is certainly not lightweight and also not easily compiled and linked into your own binary. I will have to port it myself to the embedded devide to be able to use it. Also, the device is quite limited in size.

Comment: As far as I can tell, libcurl does indeed have support for static linking, and you can choose what protocols to include in the build (so, for example, only the HTTP-related stuff). Depending on just how limited your device is, that may still be too much overhead, though.